# Python Flask: Update forms without reload

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a small program with python and flask, but I would like that when we "submit" the form, the field "input" refreshes without the page reloading, can you help me ?
Code:

HTML

```
<!-- Password -->
  <form method="post" id="app-pass">
    <label for="password_output">Your Password:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password_input" name="password_input" value="{{inpassword}}">
      <small id="password_text" class="form-text text-muted"></small><br>


  <br><br><br><br>
  <!-- Password Settings -->
    <!-- Lowercase character -->
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled> Lowercase character
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Uppercase character -->
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="uppercase"> Uppercase character
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Special character -->
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="special"> Special character
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Numbers character -->
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="number"> Numbers character
      </label>
    </div>

    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="lenght" name="lenght" value="8" max="128" min="6" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Password" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  </form>
```

PYTHON

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            settings_uppercase = request.form.get('uppercase')
            settings_special = request.form.get('special')
            settings_number = request.form.get('number')
            settings_lenght = request.form.get('lenght')
            return render_template('app/password.html', title='Password', inpassword=password_generation(settings_uppercase, settings_special, settings_number, settings_lenght))
```

the program is currently working but with a refresh of the page.
Thanks

EDIT:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var uppercase = $('#uppercase').val();
        var special = $('#special').val();
        var number = $('#number').val();
        var lenght = $('#lenght').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'passwordgen',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                document.getElementById("password_input").value = "My value";
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code works, flask gets the information but I don't know how to get the result...

Comment: If you want to update the page without reloading you will have to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: "This code works, flask gets the information but I don't know how to get the result..." What do you mean by get the result?

Comment: update the inpassword input with the result of password_generation(...)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use form without reloading it should use AJAX Calls with JQuery as following

```
$("#app-pass).on('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  data = {
           id:1
         }
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{{ url_for('file_where_is_route.functionname',parameters_of_fucntion) }}",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function (data) {
                       Here you define what to do when you have sucess call
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        to do when you have error show message
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json"
                })
});
```

Comment: I modified my post